# VBA class property with recursion

Tags: vba, class, recursion, vector, geometry

First time posting; apologies if this has been covered before, but I've not been able to find an answer.

I'm making my first foray into defining custom Classes in Excel VBA. I'm trying to create a class module for a 3D Vector that will contain three properties:

- The vector X Y and Z components (the **Vector**)
- The normalized X Y and Z components (the **Unit Vector**)
  (i.e. each of the vector components divided by the vector length)
- The vector **Length**, stored as a Double

I'd like the first and second properties to be of the same class (both as a class called cl_Vector, for example), so that they can be treated the same in subsequent calculations (both are vectors after all).

The problem is that the **Unit Vector** is related to and a function of the **Vector**, and must be revised to reflect the current components of the Vector. If they are both the same class, then I cannot reference the **Vector** components so as to update the **Unit Vector** components, without causing an infinite recursion and subsequent *Out Of Stack Space* error.

Currently I'm working with these stored as different classes, as below. Is there any way to have the **Unit Vector** nested within the **Vector**, but of the same class (i.e. recursive to one level)?

Below is my current workaround, where you'll see I have defined the **Unit Vector** as a separate class, and updated it's component values whenever the Length of the parent **Vector** is updated:

```
' cl_vector CLASS MODULE

Option Explicit

Public X As Double
Public Y As Double
Public Z As Double

' Length - read only
Public Property Get Length() As Double
    Length = Sqr(X ^ 2 + Y ^ 2 + Z ^ 2)
End Property

' Unit vector - read only
Public Property Get UnitVector() As cl_UnitVector ' <----I'D LIKE THIS TO BE STORED AS A cl_vector CLASS OBJECT
    Set UnitVector = New cl_UnitVector
    Dim pLength As Double: pLength = Me.Length ' Define temporary variable to avoid repeatedly querying
    If pLength <> 0 Then
        UnitVector.X = X / pLength ' Recalculate corresponding vector component of the parallel unit vector
        UnitVector.Y = Y / pLength ' Recalculate corresponding vector component of the parallel unit vector
        UnitVector.Z = Z / pLength ' Recalculate corresponding vector component of the parallel unit vector
    End If
End Property
```

Below is the **Unit Vector** class module:

```
' cl_UnitVector CLASS MODULE

Option Explicit

Public X As Double
Public Y As Double
Public Z As Double
```

Screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve in the Locals Window:

#### desired resulting structure

[image: desired resulting structure]

Comment: I don't get any recursion issues if I change your `cl_vector` class to use a `cl_vector` class for the type of `UnitVector`.  (Obviously it **could** cause issues, if I kept going down looking at the `UnitVector` of the `UnitVector` of the `UnitVector` ... of the original, but why would I want to do that?)

Comment: Hey @YowE3K thanks for the reply.
If you do this you'll see that in the locals window you'll have generated an infinite regression of nested vectors, right?
This seems like it must be highly inefficient. I plan to use this as part of a very large spreadsheet, so don't want to generate thousands of infinitely regressive variables.

Comment: Only if you ask to see the `UnitVector` of the `UnitVector` of the `UnitVector` of the `UnitVector` of the ...  If you don't ask to recursively go down the rabbit hole, it won't.  (It only generates a new `cl_Vector` object when each `UnitVector` property is **requested** so, if you don't invoke that property, you won't generate a new object.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.

Comment: I found a workaround:
I've changed the Unit Vector to a cl_Vector class, and avoided the recursion by testing for the length of the vector before defining a new unit vector:

    If pLength <> 0 **And pLength <> 1** Then
        set UnitVector = New cl_Vector

Comment: There isn't any recursion unless you **choose** to recursively look at the `UnitVector` property of the `UnitVector` property ..., so you don't need the `If`.  And if you include that `If` statement then your code will crash if your raw data has values for `x`, `y` and `z` of `1,0,0` for instance.  (It won't crash straight away, only when you go to use the `UnitVector` property - at which time it will try to set `UnitVector.X` where `UnitVector` is `Nothing`.)

Comment: Yep, I understand.
I was just hoping there might be a cleaner way to achieve this, as the code will be used by others also.
What you're proposing works, but seems there must be a neater way to achieve this than leaving open the potential rabbit hole.
I'm actually encountering the same problem with the relationship between nodes and vectors; a node also has a vector property associated with it - the vector from the origin to the node coordinates. And visa versa. So if each node has a vector, and each vector has a node, I end up with a rabbit hole issue there too. It's getting a bit messy

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the rabbit hole.  Consider the following line of code `Dim r As Range : Set r = Range("A1")`.  View the variable `r` in the locals or watch window, and look at its `Cells` property, or its `Areas` `Item 1` property, or its `CurrentRegion` property.  It has the same behaviour as you are seeing because various properties of a `Range` object return `Range` objects.  (Lots more people use the `Range` object than will ever use your `cl_vector` object, and the world hasn't come to an end yet! :D )

Comment: Haha yeah, this is very true. You know, I'd actually noticed that behavior before, but didn't put the two together.
Ok, thanks again for the help. I'll move on with my life :)

Comment: "I'll move on with my life" - Since when do programmers have a life?!?!